# Updating part of column in Pandas data frame with a Numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have data in a format close to that of df (shown below). My problem now is that I want to populate the data in **avg_value** with the average value for the past "days_back" days.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'DAY': np.append(np.ones(24),
                                 [np.multiply(np.ones(24), 2),
                                  np.multiply(np.ones(24), 3),
                                  np.multiply(np.ones(24), 4)]),
                'value': np.random.randn(1, 24*4)[0],
                'avg_value': 0.},
                index=pd.date_range('20150101', periods=24*4, freq="H"))

print(df.tail())
                     DAY  avg_value     value
2015-01-04 19:00:00  4.0        0.0  0.685153
2015-01-04 20:00:00  4.0        0.0  0.670713
2015-01-04 21:00:00  4.0        0.0 -0.519541
2015-01-04 22:00:00  4.0        0.0  0.795619
2015-01-04 23:00:00  4.0        0.0 -0.150966
```

Coming from R, this would be an easy thing to do..
But when I try to do

```
df.loc[df["DAY"] == the_day_I_want].avg_value = my_numpy_array
```

I get

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

So, as the good boy I am, I proceed with the following

```
index_row = df.loc[df["DAY"] == the_day_I_want].index
index_col = df.columns.get_loc("avg_value")
df.loc[index_row, index_col] = my_numpy_array
```

But I still end up with the same error! I bet there is a real easy solution to this problem but I just can't find it :/ Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are really close, need specify column in [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df["DAY"] == the_day_I_want].avg_value = my_numpy_array
```

what is same as:

```
df.loc[df["DAY"] == the_day_I_want]['avg_value'] = my_numpy_array
```

change to:

```
df.loc[df["DAY"] == the_day_I_want, 'avg_value'] = my_numpy_array
```

And why need it better explain [returning a view versus a copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

Comment: Thanks, man! Works like a charm :) 

Can't believe I was that close all this time -.-

Comment: I think it is super you was close, not necessary change a lot of code ;) Nice day and glad can help!